# Get Apache/PHP to spit out raw php code?

Tags: php, apache, encryption, base64, obfuscation

I have run into a problem... I have backups, of backups, of backups lol :)

A while back I created an advanced PHP system with my custom encryption for passwords, a kind of a raw CMS.

You have to log in, then you can see the back office, and I even made an admin panel.
I have no idea WHERE the heck my original code went as I made this a long time ago.
I could do it again, but I am just trying to save time, stress, and also I love to learn new tricks :)

I was thinking, there has to be a way to get Apache and/or PHP to spit out the code it generated.

I mean, when you go to the page, Apache and PHP read the file and present it to the browser.
So, in memory, the file is read in it's raw form and shown on screen.

Is there a way to maybe change a config file, or "mod" Apache or PHP to read the file and store the raw code in say `readfilename.php.txt`?

For example, say you took your PHP source code, and encrypted it with a simple `base64_encode`. You would have:

```
<?php
eval(base64_decode('Ly8gY29kZSBoZXJl'));
?>
```

The web server has to read it on the fly and actually see the real code.

I want to spit it out in a log file.

**I didn't use Base64 as it's too easy.**

Just a quick glance at my old code and I see SHA512 and `str_reverse`, and I have a key somewhere in there...

I don't really remember if I put anything underneath the code or not... It could be Base64 then the last method, I just can't remember the order.

I wrote a PHP script where I put the code in a `<textarea>` box and gave it a name, and it encrypted the file with my custom encryption sequence.

The code works great, *I just can't go back and edit it*.

At the time, I wasn't releasing it or using it... just making my own CMS to one day use, and probably went nuts with encrypting just out of curiosity...

I mean programmers are curious, and are hackers by nature, even if we aren't malicious and it is for our own uses!

If I can get the server to interpret the file, and instead of displaying it, spit it out into a file or present the raw code on the page, I could write another script to loop and reverse my entire project.

Saving a lot of time "reinventing the wheel" of stuff I have already done.

I am so pissed at myself for going nuts and encoding it, so hopefully someone can help... even if its in private and not public on the site, I understand.

Comment: Why do you need that? "advanced php system with my custom encryption for the passwords" --- "custom encryption" always mean something terrible and completely insecure. Your thoughts about sha512 just prove that

Comment: Uh, SHA512 is not an an encryption algorithm. It's a hash algorithm - the encryption equivalent of a meat grinder. Once you SHA something, it's hamburger, and you'll never get the original cow back again. We can't help you recover code you're not sharing, and the rest of that wall of text seems to be content free rambling/raving.

Comment: dead cow still is in the set cow, even if it's a subset :D and aren't there sha512 rainbow tables?

Comment: @Gung Foo: "and aren't there sha512 rainbow tables?" --- this question is weird. You can precalculate it "easily" if you wish.

Comment: @Gung Foo: that's where "advanced php system with custom encryption for the passwords free no banners no sms" came from

Comment: @IncomePitbull No you can't. Base64 has _nothing_ to do with encryption --- except that it can be used to encode raw bytes. SHA512 can't be used to encrypt anything because it's a hashing algorithm. Note that you always get the same number of bytes out of it no matter how many go in (:

Comment: "You can also use sha512 to encrypt code" --- no, you cannot

Comment: Can't you just connect to the server with FTP and download your files? Or do you not actually have access to the server anymore?

Comment: For the record, I have no idea WHAT I was doing. I wrote the code like a year ago. I was trying to use different methods to protect the code so people can't reverse it. I have seen tons of php systems "nulled" on the net, I was trying to protect my own code.

So ask yourself, if you spent a LONG TIME writing code, for some reason had a spurr up your ass to "protect" it, lost the original, then a year later wanted it back... what would you do? I am sure you would rather get it back than write it all over again! Not everyone is trying to be malicious!

Comment: We know you're not trying to be malicious --- you're just not making any sense. If you have access to the files...why can't you just sub `echo` for `eval`? Then `php yourscript.php` > sourcecode.txt

Comment: @shaquin  - No, I never used it. I was trying to make my own CMS system with a protected back office, ect. Kind of making my own "aMember"! Since I can program, I figured I could just make one to suit my needs exactly without extra fluff..

I had everything done, except making it look pretty (CSS, images, template, ect). I just got sidetracked on my business, and put it off. later I cam along and zipped it up for later, and somewhere along the lines deleted the originals because I thought I had it backed up... I just dont want to write it all again!

Comment: -_____________________________________________________________-

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Do all files follow the same pattern (`<?php eval(base64_decode('...')); ?>`? If they do, you may be able to create  a script that mass-extracts the code.

Comment: What is the encryption algorithm that you used? If Apache can read it, a script can reverse-engineer it.

Comment: I didn't use base64, it was just an example. I know there is sha512 in portions, but this site doesn't give enough chars to paste everything I need to really explain.. And SHA512 generates HUGE strings... I have a string of code way over the 500 char limit here...  It would just be easier to trick my webserver to "read the php" -> "spit it out raw code" (either to a file or on screen I don't care). I know you can "mod" the webserver to read the "protected code" and spit out what it actually interprets, I just don't know how. I might as well just get started coding it again lol :/

Comment: I found [this](http://www.phpcompiler.org)...

Answer (score 4):

Log in to the server (or pop open a shell prompt in the files' directory, assuming you have a local copy), change `eval` to `echo`, and execute the script at the command line (or, browse to it)...and there you go.  That's the code that would have been eval'd -- ie: the code that would run.

Let this also serve as evidence that "protecting" your source code generally doesn't even help near as much as more naive souls might think it does.  Unless you're running something like ionCube, that actually runs the encoded script directly, it's in fact near worthless -- at some point, the interpreter has to decode the script, and at that point any protection you've applied is gone.  I'd highly recommend you not bother in most cases...particularly if you're not going to keep ready copies of the original code.  :)

Comment: I voted up your answer because you seem to be the only one willing to try and help, without being a spas. I have read a lot of pages here on stack overflow and it appears a lot of people here want to reply about how "oh you should do it this way instead" or "omg that is info you could use to hack so I will just neg vote you"... People here need to lighten the heck up. Learning php and sql, could help you hack websites.. Being a programmer is being a hacker, it is how you use the knowledge that is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply disable `mod_php` and restart the Apache server. That will make all `.php` files download as plaintext.

But if you can gain priviledges on the server to do ***THAT***, you already got access to the webroot to download the files ;)

Comment: I have root to my dedicated server, so yes... Downside is, my main system has over 10k members... With about 400 people active/day, you could just foresee the HUGE influx of support tickets lol.

    
Could this also be done in WAMP so I can do it on my own computer without screwing up my membership site for the time being?

Comment: If you have access to the webroot, then you already have access to the files...

Comment: I honestly don't see the problem. thought you were looking for (strictly theoretical) hacking advice and didn't want to confess your lack of access to the system. JUST ACCESS THE DAMN FILES AT THE WEBROOT YOU PROGRAMMER YOU :P

Comment: It isn't on my system! I put the wrong set of files (the encoded ones) in a RAR file like a year ago. I found my rar file and looked at some of the files, and realized it's all protected so I can't make any changes now. So I have to write the whole thing over again, unless I can get the real files back.

A while back I heard (read it or someone told me) that they can decode any file because their system was "modded" basically, and it spits out whatever php really is reading. Either that or I can go manually to 100+ files and reverse them by hand :(

Comment: uhhmm.. echo base64decode(file_get_contents("aFileFromYourEncryptedRar.php")); echo "Gung Foo is great!";

Comment: @gungfoo - anybody can decrypt base64, hence why I DIDNT use it. It was an example illustrating how people "protect" their files. But what do you do when/if you cant. echoing an eval doesn't work in my case. I know apache/php can be "tricked" to spit it out, I have had someone tell me that's how they do it. Same instance with zend and dezender. Instead of "displaying" it, it spits out the generated code...

Comment: how does the php script "decrypt" those files then? your position seems illogical, hence all those downvotes.

Comment: @GungFoo - With a complicated script. He doesn't want to have to manually extract the code from each file.

Comment: @GungFoo By the way, it is `base64_decode` not `base64decode`.

Comment: Look, I wish I could provide the example code, I have looked at it and it is hard to read, and the encrypted sections will not fit in the char limit here anyways. I HAVE reversed many php scripts in the past, so if it was that easy I wouldn't have needed to post here. This is my own 100% coding. - So take 2 things into consideration.. I can't just echo an eval, and it is my code.  - With that in mind, when that doesn't work, is there anything else to do? As I have mentioned, I have heard of someone who modded something (either apache or php) and it just spat out the decoded code/files.

Comment: In additon to my last post: I have been looking up how, just not sure what I am looking for.. What I am doing COULD be used to decode other peoples source codes.. sure.. but a lot of "php and sql" questions asked here COULD be used for SQL Injection as well, and you guys don't have a problem answering those questions!!! - I have already stressed it is my own code, and I am in a bind here. Time is money, and dang I dont want to write something I have already done before! Its like wordpress, would you write the exact same thing as wordpress or just download it and be done in 5 minutes?

Comment: All i can tell you is that i have no idea how to output code that was interpreted by php, which can be executed but cannot be read to be put on another server. I just don't see the problem. If php can execute it, then it's fine. If you just messed around mangling variable names and such.. well bad luck because that is how php interprets the code.